# Fitting in the "call me" button

Tags: user-expectation

Going by usage, buttons should be place either close to the subject where it refers to (like the close to the phonenumber) or close to a place where the thumb will be comfortable to use.

The screen I have defined, I am wondering where I should place the "call me" button. I have placed it below, I wonder if its most intuitive. Also note that this is the only screen the customer will have a chance to call the driver. Before this the confirmation is under process.

[image: taxeeta]

Edit : 
As the app loads, the user uses all their fingers (to enter the destination). After that this screen appears as a FYI. Calling the driver is the obvious default behavior. I wonder if I should rename the GotIt to something else like, LATER. Or Thanks. This action will save the ride to `booking status` list.

Edit Again : 
This screen appears when the customer wants to know the status of the driver, ride or just talk to the driver.

Comment: Are you confident your users are using their thumbs?

Answer (score 2):

You can make an interface similar to this. Place the "Got it" button below the call. It will be more intuitive in my opinion. Considering the "OWzone" mentioned by someone in the answer, the button here seems to be in a good position to be reached by both Right hand users and left hand users.

There are both right hand users and left hand users, we should design for both of them.

[image: Call button illustration]

Comment: Chulbul Pandey :), good one..

Answer (score 2):

Have a read of Scott Hurff's article on [designing for thumbs](http://scotthurff.com/posts/how-to-design-for-thumbs-in-the-era-of-huge-screens). In it, he quotes [research by Steven Hoober](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2013/02/how-do-users-really-hold-mobile-devices.php) which found that smartphone users are most likely to use their phones held in their right hand, using their thumb to navigate the screen.

Based on that, it looks like you should move your call button out of the bottom right corner of the screen - see Thumb Zone heat map below.
[image: Thumb Zone heat map applied to every iPhone display size since 2007.]

Answer (score 1):

Since this is your primary call to action button, I would suggest that you can place in the middle with the contact number inside the green call to action button. Also, lower the importance of "Got it" button since that's the secondary action you want your user to do.

Answer (score 1):

After they enter a destination address is the app indicating to the driver somehow about the ride request? Or is the 'call me' the only action that confirms the ride? 
If the 'call me' is really important then placing it across the width of the screen would make sense. 
What is the value provided by the got it button? Does it even need to be there?

Comment: The Got IT button is line, close. I need to rename it.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Anjana.  Once you get enough rep to comment, it's better to place questions like these in the comments rather than making them a full post.